# Как лучше реализовать модель хранения сообщений CoreData?

Tags: swift, xcode, coredata

Пишу свой недомессенджер на swift4 + coredata. Посоветуйте, как лучше реализовать хранение сообщений в Core Data?

Есть идея создать 4 массива - один с моими сообщениями, второй с датами отправки каждого сообщения, третий для сообщений, которые написали мне, четвертый для дат написания сообщений мне. Но как реализовать хранение массивов в CoreData?

Comment: Если у Вас есть идеи - с удовольствием выслушаю :)

Comment: По-моему вы переусложняете. Вам достаточно иметь одну таблицу "сообщение" с полями: текст, дата отправки, от кого отправлено и к кому. (последние два поля должны быть связаны с другой таблицей). И я не понял смысла фразы "хранение массивов" для базы данных.